# Why is MySQL is returning some floats in scientific notation, but not others?

Tags: php, mysql, floating-point

I'm writing a PHP script that looks through a DB table of float values, that tend to be somewhat small, such as:

```
0.00052
0.00134
0.00103
0.00149
0.00085
0.00068
0.00077
0.00088
0.00169
0.00063
```

For reasons unknown to me, some values appear in the DB in scientific notation, such as:

1.12305e-06

The table is set to float, and I've tried all manner of functions in PHP to force the numbers to display as decimal, to no avail.  Try as I might, I'm unable to get this table of numbers to be consistently decimal in all cases.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?  Have tried typcasting to `(float)` and using `number_format()` and several other options, but no change every time.

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head, but does MySQL display values in scientific notation? I know PHP does for sure. Can you show a more complete test case of how you're handling those values?

Comment: how do you show these to find out they are in this format? Is it mysql that is returning them like this, or is it actually just php's representation? do you use `var_dump`, `echo`, `print`, etc?

Comment: Any reason you're not using a `DECIMAL` datatype?

Comment: how are you entering values to database

Comment: if you want to store a fixed format value then set `FLOAT (M.,D)` Here, “(M,D)” means than values can be stored with up to M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point.

Comment: @deceze Yes it does - if the values are small enough. Have a read of the answer I provided for more info :)

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a six digit limit on what is shown out of the CLI (and probably elsewhere). The example you have is 1.12305e-06 which is 0.00000112305 which would be shown as 0.00000 - though clearly it isn't zero.

If you are insisting on using floats or doubles, you will have to force them out using something like `round(columnName,5)` to force the display in a decimal value. Otherwise, maybe switch to a decimnal data type.

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html

Because floating-point values are approximate and not stored as exact values, attempts to treat them as exact in comparisons may lead to problems. They are also subject to platform or implementation dependencies. For more information, see Section C.5.5.8, “[Problems with Floating-Point Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html)”

Also see this [thread](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,263388) on the mysql forums about this exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my case turned out to be changing from float to decimal type in the database, so thanks to Romain for the comment that led me to look into that solution!